# Matlab-Iterating for loop with file string name

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I am trying to read in 40 files to be executed by a certain function later in the code. There are 40 files named `'Part_#_D1'`, the `#` is a number between 1 and 40.
How can I read them in here and iterate the function on it? I was trying to use the `%d` thing and use the `i` but it keeps failing. How am I using this incorrectly?

```
for i = 1:40
    img_part = imread('[/Users/cocosci/Desktop/H_All/,'Part_%d','/','Part_%d_D1.jpeg']'),i;
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're just performing the horizontal concatenation of strings which doesn't suppoert any format specifiers. You can only use the `%d` format specifier (or any format specifier) when using either `sprintf` or `fprintf`. In your case, you'll want to use `sprintf` to generate a string.

```
for k = 1:40
    filename = sprintf('/Users/cocosci/Desktop/H_All/Part_%d/Part_%d_D1.jpeg', k, k);

    % Store each image in a cell array element
    img_part{k} = imread(filename);
end
```

And then you can access a particular image with

```
% Access the third image
img_part{3}
```

Also, consider using `k` as your loop index rather than `i` since `i` is a built-in for `0 + 1i`.

Comment: Thanks!! Do I put that under the for loop, how do I get it to understand that i is 1-40?

Comment: @user3290443 I just updated it to include the explicit loop. Also, it will generate a new filename for each `k` value since that is inside of the loop.

Comment: Do I need just 1 k or 2? Since I used %d twice?

Comment: @user3290443 Oops you need two! I didn't see that second one when I posted initially. Updated now

Comment: (Yay, teamwork!) Ok cool, and then does it store all these in k? How can I see the values inside?

Comment: @user3290443 No, the way that you have it written the image data is stored within `img_part` and is *over-written* every time through the loop. I have included an alternative above which stores all images in a cell array.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!!